# How Motion Vector Prediction or Motion Vector Difference provide compression in encoder?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra, h.264, video-encoding

I know the fact that if MVP is predicted accurately, a small MVD is obtained and can be encoded using fewer bits. Our goal is to minimize MVD such that fewer bits are allocated to encode MVD that results in compression.
Can someone explain me this using Linear transformations and Dot products in Mathematical way?
Any help would be appreciated :)